# Android Refreshing Service after AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, refresh, page-refresh

I am trying to re-initiate the entire function of download and uppdate service when an AsyncTask in my activity is being called but I am not sure if I am doing something wrong. Currently, I have a refresh button that initiates the AsyncTask:

Refresh function that initiates AsyncTask:

```
    final ImageView refreshBtn= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spin_refresh);
    Log.i("RootActivity:setupHeader","******ImageView refreshBtn******");
    //Listening to Button Click by User
    refreshBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("RootActivity:setupHeader","******OnClick,Call RefreshTask******");
            //CALL ON THE CLASS OF REFRESHTASK ASYNCTASK
            RefreshTask refreshtask = new RefreshTask();
            refreshtask.execute();
        }
    });
```

Once my refresh function is called, it will call onto the refreshtask within my activity:

```
public class RefreshTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Integer,Long> implements Observer{
// SET THE PARAMETERS FOR REFRESHTASK IN ASYNCTASK: PRE-EXECUTION, PROGRESS UPDATES & POST-EXECUTION    

private Context context=null;
private DownloadService callback =null;
protected boolean exitAsync = false;
public static Hashtable<String, Download> downloadList;
final public static String PATH = "/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA/";
private static final Long START_STICKY = null;
Intent intent;
ListView lv;
RelativeLayout rl;
protected String dSResponse = null;

 public void UIThreadProgress(Context context, DownloadService callback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.DownloadService = DownloadService;
    }
//PROCESS IN CALLING THE DOWNLIST WHILE IN BACKGROUND
protected Long doInBackground(Void...params){

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("----------RefreshAsyncTask----------", "doInBackground");

    try {
        // ====================DownloadService
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        while (this.callback.condition())
        Intent i= new Intent(context.this, UpdateService.class);
        Intent I= new Intent(context.this,DownloadService.class);
        // potentially add data to the intent
        context.this.startService(i); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }while (!exitAsync);    
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //UpdateServiceStatus
}

//HANDLES EVENTS ON THE UI-POST-EXECUTE
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Long result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    lv.findViewById(R.id.spin_refresh).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Log.i("----------RefreshAsyncTask----------", "onPostExecute");
    //GIVE FEEDBACK ON THE USER INTERFACE
    Toast.makeText(context, "Your document has been refreshed and contains the updated documents!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // After the process in doInBackground has been completed   
}

}
```

Please help, I am trying to re-instantiate the download and update service when AsyncTask is being called.

Comment: Dude, if your Asynctask has been made assuming it will terminate only when both your UpdateService and DownloadService finishes there job, then you are so wrong here. first your AsyncTask will termniate just after starting the service, so having AsyncTask just to start couple of service sound redundant for me.

Comment: @Techfist the UpdateService and DownloadService only runs once, that is when the app is first launched. Hence, I am trying to use AsyncTask to invoke another function call from DownloadService and UPdateService when refreshed button is clicked

Comment: @Techfist How does Async terminates when I have tried to call the 2 servies to run in the background?

Comment: Man, starting service is an asynchronus call it not synchronus, hence asynctask doesnt care about anything after calling startService so it chooses to terminate.

Comment: @Techfist, so it would never start the context call for updateservice and downloadservice?Then how should i call the 2 services when refresh bttn is clicked?

Comment: I never said it wont start, What am saying is having AsyncTask just to start service is irrelevant here. You can simply put code for starting service inside onClick event of your button.

Comment: And yes ofcourse, if you need some kind of notification mechanism where service will notify you back once download finishes, this can be acheived in multiple ways, like by an listener, or an handler or but restarting activity and refreshing views. or by changing your design itself, by simply elemenating need of service, and using thread to let download your data and using observer design mechanism for notification.

Comment: @Techfist  Alright, I think I have got it, thanks!!So, I do not really need to use AsyncTask at all but to just call my new intent on Download and Update services in onClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand why you start a service inside a thread. You should start a thread in a service instead. Check Local Service sample in this link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

In your `onClickListener` just unbind service and bind it again. It will refresh your service. In `onCreate` method of your service start your download or update in a thread.

**Note:** It is better to use another thread mechanism for network service. AsyncTask is good for short-lived operations.

Comment: onClickService, is just used to initiate the function call of the refresh button

Comment: What you mean with onClickService?

Comment: i am sorry, i meant onClickListener

Comment: Alright, I think I have got it, thanks!!So, I do not really need to use AsyncTask at all but to just call my new intent on Download and Update services in onClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result){
super.onPostExecute(result);
lv.findViewById(R.id.spin_refresh).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Log.i("----------RefreshAsyncTask----------", "onPostExecute");
//GIVE FEEDBACK ON THE USER INTERFACE
Toast.makeText(context, "Your document has been refreshed and contains the updated       documents!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

RefreshTask refreshtask = new RefreshTask();
        refreshtask.execute();
// After the process in doInBackground has been completed   
}
```

Comment: I dont understand the rationale for you to put the refresh.execute at onPostExecute